# Haskell: What does "uses" do in control lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm new to Haskell. I was reading the code [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-sl/blob/04dc8e4a640a62f0d82633f3a78ab3d8540fd5e6/lrc/Pos/Lrc/Fts.hs#L219) and I'm not sure (though I can guess) what `uses` do:

```
inRange <- uses fsCurrentCoinRangeUpperBound (coinIndex <=)
```

Also, why's `<-` been used?

I've looked up for "Control lens uses in Haskell" but I couldn't find any explanation.

Comment: You have read the [_documentation_ on `uses`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:uses), and know how to [generally find documentation](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=uses)? It makes very seldom sense to rely on Google for finding out about some Haskell function, the specific engines Hoogle and Hayoo are much better.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Another option for navigating docs faster - and offline - is Dash or Zeal

Comment: @nicolas the default Zeal database on Haskell isn't particularly complete though – is there an easy way to extend it, or Dash's? Else I'd say a local Hoogle together with locally-install haddocks is more useful for offline help, since it works for any installed package.

Comment: @leftaroundabout You can use haddocset https://github.com/philopon/haddocset/ works great for me. I wish stackage would generate that automatically

Answer (score 1):

The first hit for a Google search on "haskell control.lens" gives me this:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens.html

...the documentation for the Lens package where the `uses` function comes from. From there, it's not actually straight-forward to determine which exact module defines this function. It turns out it's `Control.Lens.Getter`:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v:uses

So that's how you track down the documentation for random Haskell functions. Whether that documentation is actually helpful varies considerably...

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had a look at it, but I didn't know it was part of "Getter".

Comment: Thinking about it, you could perhaps have discovered that by asking GHCi with the `:i` command. I hadn't thought of that. (I don't have this package installed myself.)

Comment: This is a big shortcoming of the `lens` docs, in my opinion. It's difficult to tell where a given combinator comes from. I'd love there to be a big "index" page with every combinator listed out, so you can cmd-F and find the one you're looking for.

Comment: Uh.  You guys are aware of haddock index pages, right? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.3/docs/doc-index-All.html

Comment: @Carl I am now! Thanks, this is exactly what I had in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is the type + haddoc extra bits, and vice versa.

For instance we can see

`uses :: MonadState s m => LensLike' (Const r) s a -> (a -> r) -> m r`

That the return value is like a burrito (hence the `<-`. which gives you the current filling to grow a bigger burrito)